# Updatepanel in ajax always runs page_load Event?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, pageload

I'm new to ajax and using visual studio 2005 and framework 2.0. A simple Ajax sample always takes to the page load event for a button click. No deployment and all just running in debug mode takes me to the `Page_Load` event. Don't know what is the problem? I have checked the values of `UpdatePanel1.IsInPartialRendering and ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack` which is **false**. 
Here is my code,

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" >
    </asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="PostBack" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()+UpdatePanel1.IsInPartialRendering+ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack;
}
```

Google and stackoverflow doesnt help me so far. So any kind hearts help me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Control Inside  Update Panel Cause `asynchronous postback`.
What is Asynchronous Postback?
From Refrence To MSDN

`An asynchronous postback behaves much like a synchronous postback. All the server page life-cycle events occur, and view state and form data are preserved. However, in the rendering phase, only the contents of the UpdatePanel control are sent to the browser. The rest of the page remains unchanged`.

Now if it cause all event on server than what is the use of Partial Rendering...

> Partial-page rendering removes the need for the whole page to be
>   refreshed as the  result of a postback. Instead, only individual
>   regions of the page that have changed are  updated. As a result, users
>   do not see the whole page reload with every postback, which makes user
>   interaction with the Web page more seamless

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got that asynchronous postback calls page load. But, the second part u explained as _"users do not see the whole page reload with every postback"_ means `Page_Load` doesnt get trigger or what? sorry I coudnt get clearly...

Comment: @Developer page load triggers...all life cycle of page on server is triiger but it only render the part from server which is need to be updated...thats each and every event of page life cycle fires on server

Comment: Again a small doubt, what's the 2 _false_ returned by the two attributes `UpdatePanel1.IsInPartialRendering` and `ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack`?

Comment: Use the IsInAsyncPostBack property in combination with the IsPostBack property to distinguish between the initial page load, a partial-page update, and a full-page update in Load, InitComplete, or PreRender events.

Comment: The IsInPartialRendering property is intended for use by control developers who want to know when an UpdatePanel control is being updated as a result of an asynchronous postback. In page development scenarios, use the IsInAsyncPostBack property to determine whether a page is processing as a result of an asynchronous postback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty on my Web.forms, but as I recall, that is by design. The Page_Load does fire when an AJAX update panel sends a request to the server.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. But, the purpose of ajax and using updatepanel is to avoid full page postback right? then, how could i achieve partial postback and rendering?

Comment: I need to achieve partial postback and rendering. Hence, page_load shoudnt get triggered.. Any Help regarding this.?

Comment: Plz remove this answer and add it as comment... Due to this answer nobody viewing this question. Kind help. I want to solve the issue...

Comment: @Developer I see that another person has answered, so there is no point in me removing mine. You are missing the point of Stack Overflow. If you asked the wrong question, you should mark the correct answer as correct and then ask the question that you need to ask again.

Comment: @Developer I don't think your question was silly. I encourage you to ask more. I think you should have marked one of the answers as correct (as you now have). Following that, you would have know better what you wanted to ask. You should have then started another question. You should not ask a responder to delete their answer. Especially when it is correct (as mine was). Otherwise, I wish you all the best in your coding endeavours.

Comment: Thanks sir, I'm sorry. I misunderstand the concept. That's the problem. Thanks for your help and advice.